# convergence of sum of exponential of random walk

Tags: probability, markov-chains, random-walk

I am trying to solve the question:
Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be i.i.d., $\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_1=-1)=1/2$, and $S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$.
Prove that the following random variable converges in distribution as $n\to\infty$, and identify the limit:
$$
\left(\sum_{k=1}^ne^{S_k}\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}
$$
Thoughts: It is sufficient (right?) to show the convergence of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\log \sum_{k=1}^ne^{S_k}$. My guess is that it goes to $0$ (so that the required limit is $e^0=1$). I found a [paper](https://books.google.com/books?id=kCj-vQAACAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) discussing the convergence of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^nf({S_k})$ but there isn't a complete version online. Perhaps [law of iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) might help?

Comment: Did you mean to have a log of the sum in the line "It is sufficient..."

Comment: I can't quite figure out what the question is. Also, this looks like a homework question. Sometimes, you will be in an environment where only you know how to manage that small local environment you're in right then. If this is a homework question, I think it works better for you to ask your teacher for help to understand the material and once it gets narrowed down to a specific problem, you can think for yourself how to solve it. The general problem solving skills are what you need in the real world. I'm 35. I remember that I passed university 10 years ago and had general problem solving

Comment: skills but I no longer remember the details of the material. I believe I still have general problem solving skills. You always have to solve the problems at hand each year even if that year is gonna get so buried the year after that. You have to keep thinking independently of the past for ever because new stuff comes at the same rate as the past is getting buried.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $M_n$ be the maximum of $S_1,\dots,S_n$ and let $Z$ be a standard normal random variable. It is a well known  consequence of the reflection principle and the CLT that $M_n/\sqrt{n}$ tends to $|Z|$ in law; it also follows from Donsker's invariance principle, see Theorem 5.25 page 134 in [1].
Observe that
$$
   e^{M_n} \le   \sum_{k=1}^n e^{S_k}  \le n e^{M_n}
$$
so
$$
    {M_n} \le  \log\left(\sum_{k=1}^n e^{S_k}\right) \le {M_n}+ \log n \,.
$$
Thus
$$
     {\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}  \log\left(\sum_{k=1}^n e^{S_k}\right)  
$$
tends in distribution to $|Z|$, whence
$$
    \left(\sum_{k=1}^ne^{S_k}\right)^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}
$$
tends in distribution to $e^{|Z|}$.

[1] Mörters, Peter, and Yuval Peres. Brownian motion. Vol. 30. Cambridge University Press, 2010.
https://www.yuval-peres-books.com/brownian-motion/